# Matlab's symbolic math toolbox can't evaluate simple integration

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I want to calculate this integration symbolically in Matlab:

```
syms z mu t k

f(z,mu) = exp(-(z-mu)^2);

a(t,k) = exp(-t/k);

int(f(z,mu)*a(t-z,k),z,[0,t])
```

But Matlab can't evaluate the result. Mathematica can easily compute this integral. I cannot send the terms from Mathematica to Matlab by MatLink so I decided to do everything in Matlab.
Is there any way to compute this integral? I don't want to do this numerically because this would be slower than integrating symbolically and then giving it inputs.

### Edit

The given answer works for the above example but it doesn't work for this one:

```
syms z mu t k del

f(z,mu) = exp(-((z-mu)/del)^2);

a(t,k) = exp(-t/k);

int(f(z,mu)*a(t-z,k),z,[0,t])
```

I divided `(z-mu)` in the exponential function by the symbolic variable `del`.

Comment: Is that integral equivalent to a Laplace transform? If so, maybe you can compute it via a Laplace transform function in Matlab (I don't know the name of it) or look it up in a table.

Comment: the upper bound in Laplace transform in infinity, but here it is variable t.

Comment: Good point. Actually, it is a convolution, isn't it? In that case you could use the identity `L(f*g) = L(f) L(g)` where `f*g` is the convolution of f and g and L is the Laplace transform.

Comment: Are all of of your symbolic variables potentially complex (the default) or do you know if any/all are real? Do you know if any of the variables are restricted to particular domains, e.g., are any > 0 or >= 0 or some other set of bounds? When doing symbolic math in Matlab you need to take advantage of [`assumptions`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/assumptions-1.html) in order to simply and help solve your problems.

Answer (score 4):

Simplify the expression first, then it works

```
clear all
syms z mu t k
f(z,mu) = exp(-(z-mu)^2);
a(t,k) = exp(-t/k);
int(simplify(f(z,mu)*a(t-z,k)),z,[0,t])
```

ans

```
-(pi^(1/2)*exp(-t/k)*exp(1/(4*k^2))*exp(mu/k)*
           (erf(mu - t + 1/(2*k)) - erf(mu + 1/(2*k))))/2
```

Matlab 2015a, windows 7

Comment: If I use `exp(-((z-mu)/del)^2)`, it cannot calculate it. I just divided `z-mu` by `del`.

Comment: @yashar  Is this a new question? I answered the question posted. If you have different input please make new question since it is hard to answer 2 different questions in same place and I do not know what del is and what you had now from what is shown originally.

Comment: This is the same question actually. I didn't think that removing an extra symbolic variable would make a difference. I will edit the question.

Comment: Please do not edit the question like this. Now the answer does not reflect the original question. You can add to it, below, under `edit` and say a follow up.  Now the answer does not reflect the new question.

Comment: By changing of variable I can get the answer but I would like to get it directly from Matlab without manipulating the exponential function.